# How to change url of Ext.window.Window in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I am creating model dialog using ExtJS. Below is the Code for it,

```
var win;
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        var button = Ext.get('copy_button');

        button.on('click', function(){
            win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Copy Existing',
                height: 400,
                width: 500,
                layout: 'fit',
                modal: true,
                loader: {
                    url: '<%= request.getContextPath() %>/demo/copy.action',
                    autoLoad: true
                }
            });

            win.show(this, function() {
                button.dom.disabled = false;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The resulting page in the popup contain one button. On click of this button I want to call struts2 action means I want to change url of popup.

If I use `window.location` to call struts2 action then it changes url of parent window instead of pop up window. Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window variable is an object reference to the current browser window. This would be useful in this situaton.

As you are using `loader` in the window component you should add code to get the loader and load a new resource location using its methods. Something like this should work.

```
button.on('click', function() {
   var loader = win.getLoader();
   loader.load('new-url')
});
```

References:

[Loader - Load Method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader-method-load)

[getLoader method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-getLoader)